# drag and drop (res files) - android studio

Tags: android, image, drag-and-drop, android-studio

why doesn't my drag and drop function in Android Studio SDK work?
I drag my files from their original location to the folder in AS (within the program-not windows).
But it simply shows a non allowing cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember only being allowed to copy 1 file at a time if copying through the IDE. Is this also the case for you?